# How do I get an image URL?

Tags: email-signature

Please help, need it for email signature on Mailbird platform. I have tried different approaches. Struggling to make sense of it

Answer (score 1):

- find an image you want
- right-click on it
- select **Copy image address**
- paste where you need so with **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>** + **<kbd>V</kbd>**

[image: 0]